# Error on building babel package?

Tags: miktex, babel, l3build

I want to build new babel version to may local tex (I use MikTex64 on windows 10x64). I tried to build the package with:

```
luatex build.lua install --texmfhome "D:\localtexmf"
```

but I had error:

```
D:/MiKTeX/scripts/l3build/l3build-unpack.lua:87: attempt to index a nil value
```

Comment: l3build and miktex don't go well together.

Comment: @ulrike-fischer, OK, I tried to compile with texlive 2022, it was built successfully.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer can I use built package by texlive 2022 with MikTeX x64?

Comment: sure, but why do you need to build it? babel is updated regularly anyway.